# Determine DISK IO for a specific process in linux

Tags: linux, disk, io

I have an application that I am working on a sorting algorithm for a large data set. I want to calculate the effect of I/O in this algorithm.
Does counting the number of reading and writing operations together give me the number of I/O required for this operation?

I used a lot of tools in Linux like `iotop` and `iostat` but what I want is to show the I/O consumption on my hard disk.

Is there a better way to count the number of I/O operations or its consumption?

Comment: see [How to check disk I/O utilization per process?](https://serverfault.com/q/169676/482932)

Comment: what's "I/O consumption"?

Comment: by the way, "number of IO" is interesting for debugging and for a first step at optimizing a sorting algorithm, but says very little about performance. Makes a difference whether you query 1000 pieces of data that are Gigabytes apart in your files or drives and jump forth and back, or whether you query 1000 pieces of data that are contiguous in memory (and thus allow the operating system to prefetch, buffer). There's also the fact that on spinning disks, seeking to a different position takes *very* long time, whereas on SSDs, it's as expensive as any other read.

Comment: So the things you need to optimize heavily depend on 1. the hardware you're using, 2. the amount of RAM to buffer read data and 3. the size of your actual data you need to sort. "a large data set" sounds like something upwards of 16 GB of a properly structured database to me, but for some people it sounds like 10000 rows of a CSV file. This *really* makes a difference, and I think you should write it out in your question!

Comment: What I want is to do a statistic for the IO processes in my algorithm on Linux. I have a 20 GB file with 8 GB RAM. When I run the iotop command, it shows me the number of read and write operations and io shows me as a percentage. What does this percentage mean and how can I compare it with another algorithm?

Comment: I've used commands like `iostat -dmx 10` in the past to get extended statistics (`-x`) for devices (`-d`) with r/w rates in megabytes per second (`-m`, but `-h` may be more readable), accumulated over 10-second periods.  You can specify the desired disk devices in further arguments.  I mention this because it can show the reads per second and writes per second that you're asking for.  It shows the total reads/writes on the device, though, not per process.